# How to for_each and then count them in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to go through an iterator, select certain elements, do something with each of them, and then count how many of them were affected:

```
let done = foo
  .into_iter()
  .filter(...)
  .for_each(|i| do_something_with(i))
  .len();
```

This doesn't work since `for_each` doesn't return an iterator. The best option I found so far is this:

```
let mut done = 0;
foo
  .into_iter()
  .filter(...)
  .for_each(|i| { do_something_with(i); done += 1; });
```

Maybe there is a more elegant immutable one?

Comment: You can replace `.for_each(|i| ...)` with `.map(|i| ...).count()`.

Comment: @user4815162342 this is certainly possible, but not idiomatic. Mapping is supposed to transform a Type<T> to a Type<U> and even though mapping to unit would work here, this is not what map is for. The accepted answer is correct.

Comment: @leo848 I don't contest the correctness of the answer, just providing an alternative. Since the desire is to count, transforming to () and counting is exactly what you want to do here (and how it was typically done before `inspect`, itself far from _idiomatic_, got introduced. `inspect` simply provides a bit of sugar for that. Even then it's not a perfect substitute for `for_each` (and `map`) because it only gives you a shared reference to the element, whereas the former give you owned value.

Comment: Given that [_"It’s more common for inspect() to be used as a debugging tool than to exist in your final code"_](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.inspect), I'd argue that `map` is the more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do something on each element, but do not consume ownership of the elements, then [`Iterator::inspect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.inspect) is the method to use.

Another problem in your code is that `Iterator::count` should be used instead of `ExactSizeIterator::len`.

Example code:

```
use core::fmt::Debug;

fn do_something_with(i: impl Debug) {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}

fn main() {
    let foo = [1, 2, 3];
    let done: usize = foo
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|x| x % 2 == 1)
        .inspect(|i| do_something_with(i))
        .count();
    
    println!("{done}");
}
```

Comment: Using `inspect()` is ok if you only need the reference to the items produced by the iterator. `for_each()` gives out owned items, and if that's needed, `.map(|x| ...).count()` is the way to go.